# Called method name inside FakeItEasy.Invokes()

Tags: c#, .net, fakeiteasy

`FakeItEasy` is amazing. A big "thank you" to all the contributors.

Having said that, I ran across a use case where I would like to know from inside the lambda configured with `Invokes` what method of the faked object was actually invoked, without having to explicitly configure `Invokes` for every method.

Here is a simple example of what I mean:

```
public interface ILogger {
    void Info(string msg);
    void Error(string msg);
}

var logger = A.Fake<ILogger>();

A.CallTo(logger).Invokes(
    () => {
        Debug.WriteLine(CurrentMethodName); 
        // CurrentMethodName should return "Error", or "Info", as appropriate
    });

logger.Error("Error");
```

Inside the lambda for `Invokes`, I would like to be able to tell what method on the interface was called. In other words, how do I implement `CurrentMethodName`?

This is what I tried:

```
public string CurrentMethodName
{
    get
    {
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
        StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(1);
        return sf.GetMethod().Name;
    }
}
```

The reason it doesn't work is that `logger.Error` is not in the call stack at all at this point. What is in the call stack is something like `blah_blah_blah.AnonymousMethod__7_0()` which is the anon. method supplied to the `Invoke`.

However, at the time `CurrentMethodName` is called `FakeItEasy` must be able to know what is being faked...

Is there a parameter, or global variable, or something I can access to see that indeed `logger.Error` was called?

Furthermore, can I list the values of arguments it was called with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glad you enjoy FakeItEasy.

There are several `Invokes` overloads. If you use one that takes an `Action` on the received call, you can achieve what you want:

```
A.CallTo(logger).Invokes(call =>
     Debug.WriteLine(call.Method.Name));
```

The `call` parameter knows a lot about the call, including the arguments passed in, accessible via `call.Arguments` or `call.GetArgument`.

Alternatively, you can get the arguments (up to 4 of them) directly by using an action that accepts the matching number of parameters:

```
 A.CallTo(logger).Invokes((string message) => Debug.WriteLine(message));
```

Comment: Fantastic! FakeItEasy makes things so easy that I knew I was missing something very simple. :-) Thank you.